# Discord.py changing roles results in 403 error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The bot should add the user to Example Role on joining but it just gives me an error, help, please.

My Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name='Example Role')
    await client.add_roles(member,role)
```

Error:

```
>   Ignoring exception in on_member_join Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py",
> line 307, in _run_event yield from getattr(self, event)(*args,
> **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\Eco bot.py", line 27, in on_member_join await client.add_roles(member,role)   File
> "C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py",
> line 2905, in add_roles yield from self._replace_roles(member,
> new_roles)   File
> "C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py",
> line 2876, in _replace_roles yield from
> self.http.replace_roles(member.id, member.server.id, roles)   File
> "C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py",
> line 133, in request raise Forbidden(r, data)
> discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Missing
> Permissions
```

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like you are making some type of request to a server which you are not authenticated for.  Without more details on what you are doing, it will be very difficult to assist further.

Comment: Does your bot have the `manage_roles` permission?  Are you trying to change a person who is higher on the hierarchy than you are (The you can't edit people who come before you in the list of members)?  Are you trying to edit the server owner?

Answer (score 0):

The bot did not have the manage_roles permission, and I moved the bot to the top of the list so it can edit anyone under. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give the bot the Manage_roles permission and also note the bot can't change users when they are higher on the hierarchy.